# Googlebot CSS / JS / Images but not indexed

Tags: joomla, googlebot

Like some of you we have received emails from Google webmaster tools about CSS and JS files that were "blocked" for their crawler so we had to allow them in the robots.txt. No problem here.

But now GoogleBot need to access images, but we do not want them to be indexed in google images search. So is there a way to let GoogleBot access them but not index them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
Disallow: /images
```

to your `robots.txt` file.  Robots.txt is what you use to control what is indexed not just by Google but by any legitimate bot (since they look for that file).

That will prevent indexing but I'm not sure what you would mean by "allow access."  The rendered pages will still contain the images so any snapshot or preview should still be okay.

Update

You're right you specified that you did not want them blocked but you did not want them indexed.

For this you need to use `noindex`.
Google suggests putting this in your robots file:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /
```

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308?hl=en

Comment: Hi, doing this will make googlebots not able to see the images. When you are using GWT and do a "explore like a googebot" you have warnings of ressources that a googlebot can't access (even if, like you said, it's silly because they are visible in a browser). So I've notifications al the time saying that the images are blocked for bots and the website doesn't "pass" their "mobile friendly" test.

Comment: Just because Google says it doesn't have access does not mean you have to give it access. We do NOT all work for Google. At times there is confidential data inside images (imagine if you show a photo of someone who is being stalked and the photo has location information).  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en  you could use `noindex`.

Comment: Elin : I agree about google, but the noindex means the whole page will not be indexed, not just the images.

Comment: Not true if you specify as shown in the linked page and in my updated answer.